# Can't read image path: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /assets/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an image named `test.jpg` in my assets/images folder.

**I'm trying to read the image in my controller:**

```
    image_path = ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("test.jpg")
    image_data = File.read(image_path)
```

I get the following error:

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /assets/test-80cc818a7ee3f5d3cab23996fb09f4685b38b78258084a1ff23eca1c626646f6.jpg
```

Any ideas? Why is it appending that code to my image url? Can I get rid of it so it can read the original image url?

Thanks!

Comment: images are fingerprinted. you can read more here -> https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark. Also, you can access files in similar way -> https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets

can you try `ActionController::Base.helpers.image_url('test.jpg')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, basically asset_path returns a URL-path, relative to the root domain - ie. `"/assets/test-{SHADigest}.jpg"`.
That path is not a path for the file system, that `File.read` will accept, therefore, on unix systems you're trying to access the file system at `/assets/xyz`, like had it been `/home/xyz`-path.

What you can do, is either read from file system, raw file (Ignoring any thing the asset pipeline may or may not be set up to do)

```rb
image_path = Rails.root.join("assets", "images", "test.jpg")
image_data = File.read(image_path) # Maybe check with File.exist?(image_path) as well.
```

Or you can read from its own webserver, with any HTTP Client tool (RestClient, Net::HTTP or alike), and use `asset_url` instead of `asset_path`.
This won't work in rails console unless the server is "accidentally" running, and reachable on `config.asset_host` from where ever the rails console is running.